# Array of tuples as a struct datatype in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use a array or list of tuple2 as a column in a dataframe.  When I attempt to use the following struct type:

```
   ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField("_1", StringType), StructField("_2", BinaryType)))
```

Then add tuple2 elements to a list or an array and then add it as a row element using a row encoder with the struct type mentioned above, I get an exception with the following message:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external type for schema of struct<_1:string,_2:binary>
```

I tried to pattern my struct type after the struct type used in the ExpressionEncoders tuple method.  Any ideas? Am I not allowed to use a Tuple2 as a column type? If so, why is there an Encoder for it?  Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Case classes didn't work for me either. I got the same error when I used a case class one of the columns of my dataframe.  Instead of "scala.Tuple2", it would just say the name of my case class in the exception message.

Comment: I am wondering if I cannot use a specialized type as a single column type of my dataframe.  My struct type looks similar to this:

           val struct = StructType(StructField("id", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("label", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("src", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("dst", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("properties", ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField("_1", StringType), StructField("_2", BinaryType))))) :: Nil)